# Using semi-unstructured INI files

Tags: c++, ini

I’m looking for a way to use semi-unstructured INI files in C++ (MFC/ATL are options) such as the following example.

```
[Fruits]
Apples
Bananas
Cherries

[Colors]
Red
Orange

[Stooges]
Curly
Larry
Moe
Shemp
```

One work-around is to add numbers to every entry in each section so that they can be read with a simple while loop, passing a counter (converted to a string) as the key. Unfortunately this make maintenance unpleasant since adding or rearranging items requires keeping track of the numbers and removing items is even worse.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I’ve tried several classes that facilitate using INI files, but none support this format.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to tell us what language(s) you'd be working in.

Comment: Duh. `:-D` I knew starting and nearly finishing a new program without issues at 2am was too good to be true.

Comment: I am thinking this is not ini format hence you would have to do custom string processing

Comment: @JamesMohler, no, not the official (if such a thing exists) INI format because it *requires* key-value pairs; this is a simpler (if that’s even possible) format derived from it.

Comment: How about: `fruits=Apples,Bananas,Cherries` or some other delimited format?

Comment: @JamesMohler, the point to using a simple plain-text format like this is so that it can easily be manually edited with a text-editor. Using delimiters would complicate things and make it a mess to edit without the program (which is why I want to avoid using an index since it would be a nightmare to manually edit in addition to the waste of space).

Comment: It looks like you would have either build your own file parser, or convert an existing one. You would also have to maintain that parser. I the cost vs benefit makes it worth it, it can be done

Comment: I guess that could be done. I’m sure I’ve seen INI classes that could probably be adapted.